# Serve both internal and public facing services with traefik

Tags: traefik

I have a few services set up as docker containers in my home network with traefik acting as a reverse proxy and Let's encrypt for certificates. Once I list any service in traefik, it becomes accessible from the internet. However, I have a few services which I do not want to access from internet (internal network only) but still provide the reverse proxy service, so I can access them with a domain name rather than IP:port.

How can I set this up in traefik ? Thanks.

Comment: How are your domains validated for LE?

Comment: validated by dns challenge

Comment: In this case you can make sure that dns records for internal stuff resolve to trafik internal ip on your home network. For added security you can have second traefik instance not accessible from outside and resolve them to *that* instance.